# MySql datetime field value is returned incorrectly after querying

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am building a web application using Node.js + Express + MySQL. In each table there is a CreatedOn column which is Datetime. Whenever a record is created from the web app, in the backend I do var createdOn = new Date(); to populate this field.

When a user opens a record list page, I want to show them records created that day (today) by default. However, I can still see records that were created yesterday (only yesterday and not before that). In my database the datetime value is saved as 2016-07-21 18:01:22 when I check it through PhpMyAdmin .

My SQL query looks like this:

> select col1, col2...coln from MyTable where DATE(CreatedOn) =
>   DATE(NOW()) order by TIME(CreatedOn) DESC

When I debugged the rows from this query it seems like the CreatedOn and NOW() values have changed.

At the moment of writing this question, it is July 22, 2016 but the DATE(NOW()) show it 2016-07-20T18:30:00.000Z and it shows DATE(CreatedOn) as 2016-07-20T18:30:00.000Z as well.

Do I need to make some adjustment in the DB? or am I reading these values wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You do not need the date() function, because now returns a date.

Comment: js datetime, server datetime, mysql datetime. they might be in different timezone. make sure they are same

Comment: the server is my localhost, the database is hosted by GoDaddy and it seems it stores the correct DateTime when created in the application. However when reading it from the database it converts it to another value.

Answer (score 0):

i got that some problem sometimes when i pulled out the records give me different result but when i used Date_Format it will fixed my problem

```
Date_Format(date_field,"%Y-%m-%d");
```

Do it all of your date  field then.
Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes compare it as a result.. Date_Format helps me a lot not only once.Something to consider, the date must be look like this "2016-07-22" on that format always.. if you are using it in condition where..

Comment: Just tried it, did not work :( it still shows records I created yesterday.

Comment: what is the datatype of your CreatedOn in the database, and what is it content?

Comment: So I am using GoDaddy hosted MySql database and the datatype i am using for CreatedOn is datetime. It holds the datetime value in the following format:  2016-07-21 18:01:22

Comment: in your GoDaddy database dont have any problem? i mean the date is correct?, its just only when you pulled it out?

Comment: yeah, in GoDaddy it saves properly in the format I gave above. when i read from the database it changes to some other timezone

Comment: did you try to use SUBSTRING(date_field  FROM 1 FOR 4) just for checking of it. extract the date one by one